# Check if two values exists and return named boolean

Tags: postgresql, exists

I am trying to check if two values exists in a table, for example pseudo and email: If a user wants to signup on my website, I have to check if his pseudo and email are already taken.

So this is what I do:

```
"SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE pseudo=$1) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE mail=$2)", pseudo, email
```

("pseudo, email" at the end is because I use Golang and those are the variable that are passed in the statement)

It works, and return "false false" for example. But I would like it to return like this:

```
pseudo: false
email: false
```

But I don't know how to name the boolean that returns. I have tried this:

```
"SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE pseudo=$1) AS pseudo
UNION ALL 
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE mail=$2) AS email", pseudo, email
```

But it gives me an error.

Do you know how I could do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the result in a single row with appropriate column names, e.g.:

```
SELECT 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE pseudo=$1) AS pseudo,
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE mail=$2) AS mail
```